# How to use GDAL to import lat/lon points from ESRI File Geodatabas into MySQL

Tags: gdal, mysql, file-geodatabase, latitude-longitude

I have a file geodatabase from here:
ftp://ftp.csc.noaa.gov/temp/MarineCadastre/AIS.SampleData.zip

Using ogrinfo, I can see that it contains a layer called "Broadcast_" that has lat/lon points:

```
C:\Users\Dirk Beer\Desktop\AIS.SampleData>ogrinfo Miami.gdb Broadcast_
INFO: Open of 'Miami.gdb'
      using driver 'FileGDB' successful.

Layer name: Broadcast_
Geometry: Point
Feature Count: 1365578
Extent: (-80.282093, 25.591130) - (-79.751260, 25.950708)
Layer SRS WKT:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
FID Column = OBJECTID
Geometry Column = Shape
SOG: Integer (0.0)
COG: Integer (0.0)
Heading: Integer (0.0)
ROT: Integer (0.0)
BaseDateTime: DateTime (0.0)
Status: Integer (0.0)
VoyageID: Integer (0.0)
MMSI: Integer (0.0)
ReceiverType: String (0.0)
ReceiverID: String (0.0)
OGRFeature(Broadcast_):1
  SOG (Integer) = 0
  COG (Integer) = 77
  Heading (Integer) = 511
  ROT (Integer) = 128
  BaseDateTime (DateTime) = 2008/12/31 23:59:00
  Status (Integer) = 0
  VoyageID (Integer) = 11
  MMSI (Integer) = 366883280
  ReceiverType (String) = b
  ReceiverID (String) = 003669972
  POINT (-80.161767 25.773433)
```

I would like to import that table, with the points into a MySQL database. However, when I try, the points column does not show up in the database (the column "SHAPE" contains binary data, not lat/lon points):

`ogr2ogr -f MySQL MySQL:ais2,user=ais,password=ais Miami.gdb -lco ENGINE=MyISAM`

`show columns in broadcast_;
OGR_FID
SHAPE
sog
cog
heading
rot
basedatetime
status
voyageid
mmsi
receivertype
receiverid`

How can I import the lat/lon points?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: See also http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24888/accessing-coordinates-of-polygon

Answer (score 1):

Both your GDB file and MySQL DB do now have the spatial data -- lon-lat points -- in shape columns, but *encoded* as binary data. In computing, data types often have different *internal* and *external* representations.

You wish to see the data *presented* in lon-lat, but they are represented internally in binary. You just need to use the appropriate function to convert the points into lon-lat:

`AsText (geom_column)`

More info at [MySQL Geometry Format Conversion Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/functions-to-convert-geometries-between-formats.html).